# Azure Pipeline conditional variables not working as expected

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

This is part of my azure pipeline yaml

```
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest # Use 'windows-latest' if you have Windows native +Node modules

variables:
  ${{ if eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest') }}:
    brname: $[variables['System.PullRequest.targetBranchName']]
    isPreRelease: $[eq(variables['brname'], 'main')]
    ${{ if or(eq(variables['isPreRelease'], 'True'), eq(variables['isPreRelease'], True)) }}: # ---- not working
      releasename: $[ replace(variables['System.PullRequest.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/release/', '') ]
      format: "v{0}-rc.{1}"
      patch_version: $[counter(variables['releasename'], 1)]
    ${{ else }}:
      releasename: $[ variables['System.PullRequest.PullRequestId'] ]
      format: "PR-{0}-{1}"
      patch_version: $[counter(variables['releasename'], 1)]
    buildname: $[format(variables['format'],variables['releasename'],variables['patch_version'])]
  ${{ else }}:
    format: "development-{0}"
    buildname: $[ format(variables['format'],counter('development', 1)) ]
```

Although those intermediate variables brname and isPreRelease are not really required, i added them to debug the problem. here is the output from the variable calculation

The job parameters in pipeline look like this

```
Job preparation parameters
Variables:
  brname:
    Parsing expression: <variables['System.PullRequest.targetBranchName']>
    Evaluating: variables['System.PullRequest.targetBranchName']
    Result: 'main'
  isPreRelease:
    Parsing expression: <eq(variables['brname'], 'main')>
    Evaluating: eq(variables['brname'], 'main')
    Expanded: eq('main', 'main')
    Result: 'True'
  releasename:
    Parsing expression: <variables['System.PullRequest.PullRequestId']>
    Evaluating: variables['System.PullRequest.PullRequestId']
    Result: '473'
  patch_version:
    Parsing expression: <counter(variables['releasename'], 1)>
    Evaluating: counter(variables['releasename'], 1)
    Expanded: 16
    Result: '16'
  buildname:
    Parsing expression: <format(variables['format'],variables['releasename'],variables['patch_version'])>
    Evaluating: format(variables['format'], variables['releasename'], variables['patch_version'])
    Result: 'PR-473-16'

7 queue time variables used
system.pullRequest.pullRequestId : 473
system.pullRequest.sourceBranch : refs/heads/release/2.1.0
system.pullRequest.targetBranch : refs/heads/main
system.pullRequest.targetBranchName : main
system.pullRequest.sourceCommitId : 421e608d30116fc89a8b45ccccdcd39d982074a7
system.pullRequest.sourceRepositoryUri : https://CareAbout@dev.azure.com/CareAbout/DataIntegration/_git/data-factory
system.pullRequest.pullRequestIteration : 30
```

Why is the second if statement not being calculated correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested the issue and found that it will not work when use `${{ if eq(variables['System.PullRequest.targetBranchName'], 'main') }}:`.

The  `System.PullRequest.targetBranchName` is not available in compile time.

As a workaround, I can use `System.PullRequest.targetBranchName` in the conditions session.  The following sample is using the `System.PullRequest.targetBranchName` in job conditions and the right job will run.

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

stages:
- stage: 
  jobs:
  - job: NotPullRequest
    condition:  ne(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest')
    variables:
      format: "development-{0}"
      buildname: $[ format(variables['format'],counter('development', 1)) ]
    steps:
      - script: |
          echo "Build.Reason isn't PullRequest"
          echo  $(buildname)
  - job: PullRequestToMain
    condition:  and(eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest'), eq(variables['System.PullRequest.targetBranchName'], 'main'))
    variables:
      releasename: $[ replace(variables['System.PullRequest.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/release/', '') ]
      format: "v{0}-rc.{1}"
      patch_version: $[counter(variables['releasename'], 1)]
      buildname: $[format(variables['format'],variables['releasename'],variables['patch_version'])]
    steps:
      - script: |
          echo "Build.Reason is  PullRequest and PullRequest to main branch"
          echo  $(releasename)
          echo  $(patch_version)
          echo  $(buildname)
  - job: PullRequestToOther
    condition: and(eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest'), ne(variables['System.PullRequest.targetBranchName'], 'main'))
    variables:
      releasename: $[ variables['System.PullRequest.PullRequestId'] ]
      format: "PR-{0}-{1}"
      patch_version: $[counter(variables['releasename'], 1)]
      buildname: $[format(variables['format'],variables['releasename'],variables['patch_version'])]
    steps:
      - script: |
          echo "Build.Reason is  PullRequest and  PullRequest to other branch"
          echo  $(releasename)
          echo  $(patch_version)
          echo  $(buildname)
```

Result:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing runtime expressions (`$[]`) with compilation-time expressions (`${{}}`). `isPreRelease` isn't defined until *after* the YAML template is compiled. Compilation-time expressions are evaluated very early in the YAML pipeline, **before** runtime expressions are evaluated.

Comment: For this use case what is the recommended solution?